# How to generate a wavesurfer with multiple peak colors using videojs-wavesurfer or wavesurfer.js?

Tags: video.js, wavesurfer.js, audiowaveform

Is there a way to have multiple colors with the peaks using videojs-wavesurfer?

Please refer to the below image for ref.

[image]

Current implementation of videojs-wavesurfer with video is giving the output as below

[image]

**videojs-wavesurfer** ref link https://collab-project.github.io/videojs-wavesurfer/#/

Comment: The closest I've seen to that is the regions plugin example at https://collab-project.github.io/videojs-wavesurfer/#/plugins

Comment: Yeah, @misterben I have tried that. That is used to add different background colors but not the wave colors